# don't can use Enter key from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my project I need diable Enter key for some textbox , because i don't want post page when enter key button . I use this Code for disable Enter key :

```
$(document).keypress(
function (event) {
    if (event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Its work fine , but when  Add textarea in page , I cant enter key for break line , because Enter key disabled .

how can I enable Enter key for textarea?

Comment: if none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help. Otherwise, please mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if its recommended to attach a **global** `keypress` handler like that. Regardless, the easiest way out would be

```
$(document).on('keypress', 
function (event) {
    if (event.which == '13' && event.target.tagName != 'TEXTAREA') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

In the above, you are checking the `tagName` of `event.target` to see if the element in which the `enter` occured is a `textarea` or not

However, I would recommend this approach

```
$('form').on('keypress', 'form',
    function (event) {
        if (event.which == '13') {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

This will target **all** `input` elements and **not** `textarea` elements,

Comment: Or to handle dynamically adding/removing fields without having to worry about re-hooking, `$(document).on("keypress", "form input", ...)`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, actually thats a good point I have been wondering about. Is it better to just always us `on()`? I mean, for dynamic situations yes. But for all other cases, isnt it better to bind to the event directly? I imagine `on` has a slight performance hit, however minimal

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, guess I just answered my own question. Since it is a minor performance hit, might as well always use `on`

Comment: @AmmarCSE: :-) It's the other way around: Using `$(...).click(...)` to hook up (or call) an event handler has a ***very very very very small*** performance hit vs. `$(...).on("click", ...)`. Why? Because all `click` and the other shortcuts do is figure out whether you're hooking or triggering, and then call `on` if you're hooking or `trigger` if you're triggering. (Not like it would ever actually matter, though.)

Comment: @AmmarCSE: The reason for my suggestion above wasn't to use `.on`, but to use event delegation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, you have to be shiteing me! :) I had no idea thats how `.click` worked!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I need to read the source code more. http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.click ... Thanks for the info

Comment: @AmmarCSE: :-) https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event/alias.js#L6-17

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your form to detect the Enter key as,

```
$('#formid').on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
  if (code  == 13) {               
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
});
```

[**Here is a demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/saumil_sss/L2t6pbh2/)

By this you will be able to use the Enter key on your text area without submitting the form.